# Convert only characters to decimal in hexa string

Tags: command-line

I have the following hexa string

```
17a62
```

I want to convert it to decimal. I am using the following approach:

```
echo $((16#17a62))
```

It results in

```
96866
```

but i dont want this, i just want to replace the "alphabet character" in the string with its decimal value. Like **decimal value of a hex is 10** so i want the output to be like:

```
171062
```

How can i achieve this ? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The syntax that you are using cannot be used to achieve what you want. You should write your own script for this task.

Comment: you mean to say, i have to write my own script which iterates over each character ? There isn't any built-in method for this ? @Puspam

Answer (score 1):

Could do it with sed:

```
$ printf %d $(sed 's/./0x& /g' <<< 17a26b12)
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option, you could do something like this:

```
$ echo 17a62 | perl -pe 's/[a-f]/hex $&/e'
171062
```

If you really need to do this natively in the shell, then with bash:

```
$ hexa=17a62

$ [[ $hexa =~ ([0-9]*)([a-f])([0-9]*) ]] && printf '%d%d%d\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" $((16#"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}")) "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
171062
```